# Register composite pattern in StructureMap

Tags: c#, structuremap

In my project I use composite pattern and I want to register and resolve this hierarchy using StructureMap. 
The code looks like this

```
interface IFoo
{
    void Do();
}

class Foo1 : IFoo
{
    public void Do()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo1");
    }
}

class Foo2 : IFoo
{
    public void Do()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo2");
    }
}

class CompositeFoo : IFoo
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IFoo> foos;

    public CompositeFoo(IEnumerable<IFoo> foos)
    {
        this.foos = foos;
    }

    public void Do()
    {
        foreach (var foo in this.foos)
        {
            foo.Do();
        }
    }
}

class Bootstrapper
{
    public static void Run()
    {
        var container = new Container(c =>
        {
            c.For<IFoo>().Add<Foo1>();
            c.For<IFoo>().Add<Foo2>();
            c.For<IFoo>().Use<CompositeFoo>();

        });

        // throws exception
        var result = container.GetInstance<IFoo>();
        result.Do();
    }
}
```

The specified code throws this exception

```
Bi-directional dependency relationship detected!
Check the StructureMap stacktrace below:
1.) Instance of IFoo (CompositeFoo)
2.) All registered children for IEnumerable<IFoo>
3.) Instance of IEnumerable<IFoo>
4.) new CompositeFoo(*Default of IEnumerable<IFoo>*)
5.) CompositeFoo
6.) Instance of IFoo (CompositeFoo)
7.) Container.GetInstance<IFoo>()
```

I can not find anything related to this in the official documentation or anywhere on the internet. Is this at all possible without manually specifying all possible dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying to accomplish this using policies or factory classes, I sacked StructureMap in favour of Grace. There I can easily instantiate the composite object with the following code

```
var container = new DependencyInjectionContainer();
container.Configure(c =>
{
     c.Export<Foo1>().As<IFoo>();
     c.Export<Foo2>().As<IFoo>();
     c.Export<CompositeFoo>().As<IFoo>();
});

var foo = container.Locate<IFoo>();
foo.Do();
```

And the result is as expected:

```
foo1
foo2
```

The problem with StructureMap for me is that they do not support any way to specify dependencies for an object dynamically. I could make it work if I manually write all instances which should be injected or resolve all, including the composite object. I could probably make it somehow possible using policies with injected container and specify dependencies that way, but it is too hacky in my opinion.

Comment: Very interesting. How does it know not to inject the composite into itself? Does it have a recursion detection built-in?

Comment: BTW, I'd honestly consider removing the "accepted answer" here. Even though it works, it doesn't work with Structuremap, so it's not an answer for "making composite work with Structuremap".

Answer (score 1):

The way i see it you have a couple of options:

1. Register `CompositeFoo` as `CompositeFoo` and not `IFoo`. Then ask for an instance of `CompositeFoo`.

   ```
   cfg.For<IFoo>().Add<Foo1>();
   cfg.For<IFoo>().Add<Foo2>();
   cfg.ForConcreteType<CompositeFoo>();
   ...
   var result = container.GetInstance<CompositeFoo>();
   ```
2. Define a new interface for the composite.

   ```
   interface ICompositeFoo : IFoo {}
   class CompositeFoo : ICompositeFoo
   ...
   cfg.For<IFoo>().Add<Foo1>();
   cfg.For<IFoo>().Add<Foo2>();
   cfg.For<ICompositeFoo>().Use<CompositeFoo>();
   ...
   var foo = container.GetInstance<ICompositeFoo>();
   ```

Comment: That is not a solution, because this object may be in the middle of the hierarchy. Both propositions have the same problem, and that they have to be manually resolved or need to have the dependent objects modified to expect ICompositeFoo.

Comment: Instead of having a different interface for the composite, I suggest having a different interface for child instances, something like `IChildFoo`. That way, the same classes can implement both `IFoo` and `IChildFoo`, but the composite only implements `IFoo`. Then, you can register the child instances using the child interface and keep existing dependencies on the actual interface intact.

Using the approach you suggested, you'd have to change consumers to rely on `ICompositeFoo` instead of `IFoo`, which is far from ideal.